# Subscribe pipes/directives in AppModule without losing lazyness

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I just updated my application to RC6 and I noticed that they have deprecated @Componenet.pipes and @Component.directives.

And they suggest to import them in the module class:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HighlightDirective
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

I followed the project structure suggested in the Angular Style Guide, so I have some lazy folders (e.g. +SubscriptionPage/)

The problem is that in my "+SubscriptionPage/" folder I have some pipes/directives that I use only in that part of the application.
So if I put that pipes/directives in the RootModule, they are loaded in a eager way and not in a lazy way.

What is the correct way to use "Section Specific" pipes/directives without losing the lazyness.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a lazy module for that:
(taken from [here](https://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html))

> NgModules enable a simple way to lazy load pieces of your application via the router. A simple example illustrates this:

```
import {RouterModule} from ‘@angular/router’
import {NgModule} from ‘@angular/core’
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyComponent, MyHomeRoute ],
  bootstrap: [ MyComponent ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: ‘home’, component: MyHomeRoute },
      { path: ‘lazy’, loadChildren: ‘./my-lazy-module’ }
    ])
})
class MyAppModule {}
```

> You simply define a `loadChildren` property on a route, and Angular
>   will go fetch the module at that location and load the routes defined
>   in it into the router config.

```
import {RouterModule} from ‘@angular/router’
import {NgModule} from ‘@angular/core’

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyLazyHome, MyLazyChild ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: ‘’, component: MyLazyHome },
      { path: ‘a’, component: MyLazyChild }
    ])
  ]
})
class MyLazyModule {}
```

Comment: Do you know what **./my-lazy-module** is?
I think it is the path to the module file, but if I put the correct path I get the following Exception:

* Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'default' in './app/main/main.module'*

Comment: Do you export the class? `@NgModule({...}) export class MainModule`

Comment: What's your network tab say? Does it load the module? Maybe this is a packaging problem?

Comment: I think some guys on angular gitter might be able to help.